# Creating new View in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, layout, view

I would like to have two views. One for arithmetic series with unique layout and the same for geometric. I would like to have a button in each fragment allowing to change to either arithmetic or geometric.

I have two errors:

coma after layout inflater inflater is underlined and it reads: Syntax error on token ",", ; expected

Bundle is underlined and error is: Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement

```
public class Sequences_n_series extends Fragment {



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View ssView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ss, container, false);



        Button calc = (Button)ssView.findViewById(R.id.aritmetic); //main  button


        calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_probability, container, false);

                    return rootView;
                }

            }
        });



        return ssView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Wizard from Eclipse to create a Plug-in **and** add Views to existing plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

You've put a method declaration for `onCreateView` directly into another method declaration, `onClick`.